# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сегодня спорили на работе по поводу постановки запятой в предложении: Заседание комиссии вел председатель комиссии заместитель главы администрации Иванов И.И. Мне доказывали, что после комиссии нужно поставить запятую, я утверждала, что нет, так как приложения неоднородные. Кто прав и как правильно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, это неоднородные определения. Запятая не нужна. Ср.: ***председатель подкомиссии лидер демократов в сенате сенатор Джонсон. Но: товарищ Борисов, новатор производства, токарь***. Неоднородные приложения, стоящие перед определяемым существительным, становятся однородными в положении после определяемого слова. То же в вашем примере: ***<...> председатель комиссии заместитель главы администрации Иванов И.И.*** Но.: **Иванов И.И., председатель комиссии, заместитель главы администрации <...>.** 
***См.: Трудные случаи пунктуации. Розенталь, Былинский.***

Comment: Спасибо!!!